# How to merge spacing arrays

Tags: javascript

There is an array of intervals, it is necessary to combine overlapping, that is:

```
[[0, 33], [66, 80]] => [[0, 33], [66, 80]]

[[0, 33], [66, 80], [0, 66], [33, 100]] => [0,100]
```

Wrote the code. I get the result 
    [[0, 100], [66, 80]]. 
This is because first the range 
    [[0, 33]], then 
    [[0, 33], [66, 80]]
, then 
    [[0, 66], [66, 80]]
, then 
    [[0, 100] , [66, 80]] as if to check other ranges without looping

```
const data = [
    [0, 33],
    [66, 80],
    [0, 66],
    [33, 100]
  ];

  createDataForSlider = data =>
    data.reduce((prevVal, time) => {
      let isPrevValUpdated = false;

      const timeStart = time[0];
      const timeEnd = time[1];

      /* eslint no-param-reassign: ["error", { "ignorePropertyModificationsFor": ["prevVal"] }] */
      if (prevVal.length) {
        for (let i = 0, ii = prevVal.length; i < ii; i += 1) {
          let prevValCurrent = prevVal[i];

          if (timeStart >= prevValCurrent[0] && timeEnd <= prevValCurrent[1]) {
            isPrevValUpdated = true;
            break;
          }
          if (
            !isPrevValUpdated &&
            timeStart >= prevValCurrent[0] &&
            timeStart <= prevValCurrent[1]
          ) {
            prevValCurrent[1] = timeEnd;
            isPrevValUpdated = true;
            break;
          }
          if (
            !isPrevValUpdated &&
            timeEnd >= prevValCurrent[0] &&
            timeEnd <= prevValCurrent[1]
          ) {
            prevValCurrent[0] = timeStart;
            isPrevValUpdated = true;
            break;
          }

          //console.log("prevVal-", prevVal);
        }
      }
      if (!isPrevValUpdated) {
        prevVal.push([timeStart, timeEnd]);
      }
      return prevVal;
    }, []);

  createDataForSlider(data);
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the desired transformation more? Why does an input of 2 subarrays result in 2 subarrays, while an input of 4 subarrays results in only a single array?

Comment: are negative numbers allowed too? And if yes, should they be overlapped in negative way? for example: `[[0, -10], [-10, -20]] => [0, -20]`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance what he means, I guess, is to merge the overlapping values. In his first case, he has as input two arrays, and the last item of one array, is the first item of the second array, so this means that we can merge these two ranges, and create a single range going from the first item of the first array, to the second item of the second array. 
In the second case, the items cannot be merged in a single range, so his output is two arrays, overlapped as above in the first case.

Answer (score 2):

Try following

1. Sort Array according to the all start times
2. Now reduce it using an empty array accumulator, by comparing previously inserted frequency to the current frequency.

   ```
   const frequencies = [[0, 33], [66, 80], [0, 66], [33, 100]];

   const sortedFrequencies = frequencies.sort((f1, f2) =>{ return f1[0] - f2[0]});

   sortedFrequencies.reduce((acc, current) => {
      if(acc.length > 0 && current[0] <= acc[acc.length - 1][1]) {

           acc[acc.length - 1][1] = current[1] > acc[acc.length - 1][1] ? current[1] : acc[acc.length - 1][1];
      } else {

           acc.push(current)
      }
      return acc;
   }, []);
   ```

Comment: Fails for `[[0, 33], [66, 80], [0, 66]]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your input array first like this:

```
data.sort((val1, val2) => {
  //order by range start ASC
  let res1 = val1[0] - val2[0];

  if (res1 === 0) {
    //order by range end DESC
    return val2[1] - val1[1];
  }

  return res1;
});
```

And then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array (start ASC, end DESC) and check if start and end position is in the range of another data set, then return a new set with min and max values. Otherwise take the original values.

```js
function merge(array) {
    return array
        .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0] || b[1] - a[1])
        .reduce((t, [l, r]) => {
            var item = [[l, r]];
            if (!t) return [[l, r]];
            return t
                .map(([a, b]) =>
                    l <= a && a <= r || l <= b && b <= r || a <= l && l <= b || a <= r && r <= b
                        ? (item = [], [Math.min(a, l), Math.max(b, r)])
                        : [a, b]
                )
                .concat(item);
        }, undefined);
}

console.log(merge([[0, 33], [66, 80], [0, 66], [33, 100]]));
console.log(merge([[0, 33], [66, 80]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge overlapping 1-D arrays, .sort() will sort the 2-D array by ascending value based on each 1-D array at element 0. You can then loop through each element - 1 of the sorted 2-D array and check if the element at index i is a subset of the element at index i + 1. If so, push the element at index i + 1 to the new array.

```
function isSubSet(a, b) {
    if ((a[0] >= b[0] && a[1] <= b[1]) ||
        (a[0] <= b[0] && a[1] >= b[1])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function mergeArray(arr) {

    let newArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (isSubSet(arr[i], arr[i + 1])) {
            newArr.push(arr[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    return newArr;
}

const data = [[0, 33], [66, 80], [0, 66], [33, 100]];

let arr = mergeArray(data.sort());
```

Answer (score -2):

Loop through it again and again and again till the length of the output array is equal to the length of the input array.

If after a round there is something overlapping, the next round will merge the two and the output will be shorter.

The process will stop for sure in less than data.lenght steps.

Could not be the most efficient way from the running time point of view, but if this is not an issue I would go for it.

Comment: This is not an aswer at all. This is not even a comment.